# lxml xpath выдает случайные значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, xpath, lxml

Нужно получить ссылку с кнопки Скачать на сайте: https://ru.sefon.cc/mp3/5055-bravo-ehtot-gorod/

Прописываю путь по XPath и в итоге интерпритатор каждый раз выдает совсем разные значения и не те, которые нужно.

Код:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def lxml(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"}
    html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    tree = html.document_fromstring(html_text)
    href = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a[2]")[0].get("href")

    print(href)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lxml('https://ru.sefon.cc/mp3/5055-bravo-ehtot-gorod/')
```

Примерный вывод интерпритатора, каждый раз он случайный:

```
#RXRTTE5dTWVlCeXI3ZVQ0L2hybUhqcV9tcDNfZG93bmxvYWQvZGlyZWN8lUeVZ1NMdGNYTzJSOVo5R0LzUwNTUvM3I5M0FKRG5M1ZLMGpiQURFdzFUVVdWX1pkbTR5ONTRLLWtLalJaZVpnclNMS0ZvN2MlZVRXpvV23bzZaRW1FicS1WnRHMzlfc3YVFKVmQv0VYN5MNlhTb1KZF2FwaS9ydElTTVN2wzWDVXMFdjUjlOdVNsTmNQRFpON1HekhfcHo
```

Comment: Так и ссылка каждый раз «случайная», т.е. нет проблемы со стороны парсера, хоть и используется не самый надёжный локатор; более добротный:  `//a[contains(@href,'download')]`

Comment: Side note: ох не стоит называть функции так же, как и модули!